# How to convert a pd.Series of dict to pd.Series of string?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

How to convert the Series of dictionary below to a Series of strings.

```
import pandas as pd

dicts = {1: [{"id1":"result1", "name1":"result1"}], 2: [{"id2":"result2", "name2":"result2"}]}
# create test dataframe
df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(dicts, orient='index')
df=df.rename(columns={0:'column'})
print(df)
```

[image]

Change to:

[image]

The example above isn't the real scenario, that would be used to convert the result from an API response. I want to load it to a table, but as a string, not as dictionary (in Big Query there is the STRUCT type)

Comment: `df["column"] = df["column"].astype(str)` ?

Comment: @AndrejKesely I tried that but it didnt't work. After trying the column still a dictionary and the dtype still 'object'.

Comment: Both strings and dictionaries are objects. Try to slice one item to see the difference.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Depending on the type of quotes needed you have two options:

```
import json

df['str'] = df['column'].astype(str)

df['json'] = df['column'].map(json.dumps)
```

Output:

```
                                   column                                     str                                    json
1  {'id1': 'result1', 'name1': 'result1'}  {'id1': 'result1', 'name1': 'result1'}  {"id1": "result1", "name1": "result1"}
2  {'id2': 'result2', 'name2': 'result2'}  {'id2': 'result2', 'name2': 'result2'}  {"id2": "result2", "name2": "result2"}
```

Let's check the first row as dictionary:

```
print(df.loc[1].to_dict())

{'column': {'id1': 'result1', 'name1': 'result1'},
 'str': "{'id1': 'result1', 'name1': 'result1'}",
 'json': '{"id1": "result1", "name1": "result1"}',
}
```

Comment: Thanks! It really works. Since in the output it wasn't showing the double quotes, I thought it was still a dictionary.

Comment: @Luiz yes, pandas display is often ambiguous ;)

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
for index in df.index:
   x = str(df['column'][index])
   df['column'][index] = f'"{x}"'
print(df)
```

Output:

```
                                     column
1   "{'id1': 'result1', 'name1': 'result1'}"
2   "{'id2': 'result2', 'name2': 'result2'}"
```